# Is there a way to restrinct rolling window from summing if not 2 behind?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to sum over 3 rows (ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) using SQL ROLLING WINDOW:

The issue is that if try to use the statement ROWS BETWEEN 2 AND CURRENT ROW, it will provide SUM even if I have only ONE preceding row, and I would want to have result as NULL / 0 if there's not 2 preceding and only one.

Is there a manner to have it like that?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please tag only a single rdbms, being the one you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example that illustrate approach

```
with your_table as (
  select 1 ts, 10 value union all 
  select 2, 20 union all 
  select 3, 30 union all 
  select 4, 40
)
select *, 
  if(count(value) over win = 3, sum(value) over win, null) result
from your_table
window win as (order by ts rows between 2 preceding and current row)
```

with output

[image]

In case if you want at least one row behind - you would use

```
select *, 
  if(count(value) over win > 1, sum(value) over win, null) result
from your_table
window win as (order by ts rows between 2 preceding and current row)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: One more question: And in case i would like a higher window like 6 or 12, i just have to change the win =, right?

Comment: correct `win =` or `win <` - whatever logic you need - either all to be present or at least that many ...